# How can i revers Clickup Dock with nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want use this Clickup Doc on my homepage but return 504 badway.

But it return 502 badway.

I try it:

```
server {

    server_name sub.domain.com;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

    location / {
        
        proxy_pass https://doc.clickup.com/31186101/p/h/xqq5n-104/739a5a0867b76cb;
        uwsgi_param Host $host;
        uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    }
}
```